# Strip www. from domain works on main site but not with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have my .htaccess file as the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

when I visit my primary site at: www.site.com, the www. is stripped as it should be and all works fine.

When I visit a subdomain in proper format (http://sub.site.com) everythign works fine.

The issue comes when a user would enter www. as part of a subdomain so:
http://www.sub.site.com does not strip the www. and instead redirects to the Media temple hosted "sub-domain does not exist" page (INCREDIBLY ANNOYING by the way).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

To:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+?)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.%2$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. My code, as I mention above works for the primary domain and I utilize for several sites so I'd prefer not to hardcode the .htaccess file for the 50+ sites I manage. I'll give it a shot but I dont think that is the particular issue at hand.

Comment: @JM4 - Changed it to be more generic

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had to "trick" the system but found a working method:

I first had to create a vhost.conf file within my subdomain with:

> ServerAlias www.subdomain.site.com

After resetting Plesk and my Apache server, I also added a wildcard DNS record to my subdomain as:

> *.subdomain.site.com. A record with IP address appropriately

This seems to have resolved my issue for now though still can't figure out why the former did not work.